# $\sum_{i=1}^{∞}\sum_{j=1}^{∞}a_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^{∞}\sum_{i=1}^{∞}a_{ij}=\text{lim}_{r\to∞}\sum_{(i,j)\in rV}a_{ij}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $a_{ij} ∈ \mathbb{C}$, $i, j = 1, 2, . . $ .  If $\sum_{i=1}^{∞}\sum_{j=1}^{∞}|a_{ij}|<∞$

Then

$\sum_{i=1}^{∞}\sum_{j=1}^{∞}a_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^{∞}\sum_{i=1}^{∞}a_{ij}=\text{lim}_{r\to∞}\sum_{(i,j)\in rV}a_{ij}$.

Where  $V$ is any neighborhood in $(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $rV := \{rx : x ∈ V \}$.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: (1) Review the proof that rearrangement of absolutely convergent series does not change the sum.  Try to imitate that proof.  I think you cannot simply apply it, though.  (2) Skip all that, and apply Fubini's theorem.  Counting measures are measures, too!

Comment: I assume you don't mean that the indices $a_{i,j}$ that the $i$ and $j$ are in $rV$?  You you mean for each $(i, j)$, $a_{i,j}\in rV$?

Comment: @TravisJ: I think it is OK as stated.  Assuming $\mathbb N \subseteq \mathbb R$ in the usual way.